# JSESSIONID and hazelcast.sessionId

Tags: session, tomcat, hazelcast

currently we are deploying to a cluster-scenario where we have 3 nodes (tomcat), all of them share their sessions via Hazelcast. We have an apache in front of these nodes as a loadbalancer.

`curl`ing our application, I see, that there are two session-cookies used:

**1)** is the usual tomcat session with a `JSESSIONID`

**2)** is the hazelcast-session with a `hazelcast.sessionId`

Is there any way to *omit* the `JSESSIONID`?

or

Is there any way to somehow "join" both?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, both are required in current implementation.

Hazelcast uses only `hazelcast.sessionId` as `HttpSession.getId()` and nearly everyplace to identify distributed session. But for some cases like failover Hazelcast uses both session identifiers (`hazelcast.sessionId` and `JSESSIONID` ) internally.

[*From Hazelcast documentation*](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.3-SNAPSHOT/manual/html/websessionreplication.html):

> #### [SessionId Generation](http://hazelcast.org/docs/3.3-SNAPSHOT/manual/html/websessionreplication.html)
>
> SessionId generation is done by Hazelcast Web Session Module if session replication is configured in the web application. Default cookie name for the sessionId is `hazelcast.sessionId` and this is configurable with `cookie-name` parameter in the `web.xml` file of the application. `hazelcast.sessionId` is just a UUID prefixed with “HZ” character and without “-“ character, e.g. HZ6F2D036789E4404893E99C05D8CA70C7.
>
> When called by the target application, the value of `HttpSession.getId()` is the same as the value of `hazelcast.sessionId`.